# Force trim of query output values and add auto number

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, string-formatting

I have the below SQL Query which gives me the correct output, but the values are not displaying correctly when they are displayed on the website, and I need some how to force it correctly. The Database runs on a MS SQL 2008 R2, and the serverside language is PHP.

**The SQL Query is :**

```
SELECT a.username AS 'User Name'
    , MAX(b.game_level) AS 'Level Reached'
    , CAST(DATEADD(millisecond,SUM(DATEDIFF(millisecond,0,CAST(b.time_spent AS DATETIME))),0) AS TIME) AS 'Total Time Spent'
    , AVG(CAST(b.stars AS FLOAT)) AS 'Stars'
    , SUM(b.game_level_score) AS 'High Score'
    , a.current_state AS 'Online State'
FROM game_users a
JOIN score b ON a.id = b.game_users_id
GROUP BY a.username, a.current_state
```

**What I would like to achieve**

1 : Can the 'Total Time Spent' be trimmed so that it only display HH:MM:SS ?

2 : Is it possible to force 'Stars' to be only 1 decimal (So it displays i.e. 3.5)? When it displays from MS SQL PHP Generator that I use to publish it to the web it displays like 3.5000.

3 : Also for the 'High Score' when the value is 3565 it instead displays like 3,565.0000 which is offcause wrong and should be displayed just like 3565.

4 : Is it possible to make a counter that set 1 on the highest rank, 2 on next, 3 on third, and so on, so that the person with the highest score get rank 1 displayed at the first row?

I know that it is only the "Total Time Spent" that has additional formatting then it should have when I run the query in MS SQL Management Studio, but the reason I ask about 2 and 3 is if there are some way to force the webcode to display it correctly from inside the query?

Best Regards

Stig :-)

Comment: What database? [tag:mssql], [tag:mysql], [tag:postgresql]..? What server-side language? [tag:php], [tag:.net], [tag:ruby]..? Add the relevant tags to your question, and remove the (so far as I can tell) irrelevant 'trimming' and 'texttrimming' tags, for which I can't imagine anyone will be searching or actively following. In fact the mouse-over for those tags explicitly states: "0 followers."

Comment: Hi David.. I have now edited the thread, but I was hoping that the originally "MS SQL Management Studio" and "MS SQL PHP Generator" would have given you the clues to that we where talking MSSQL and PHP.. Also the tag has been changed, hope that corrects the thread ;-)

Comment: You're asking several questions at once which makes it hard for people to help you out.  Stack overflow is best formatted to ask a single question at a time.  With that said, I'll take a shot at a couple of your scenarios.

Comment: I've updated the answer below with a better cast. In the future try and limit questions to a single topic and you'll get a lot more help. Each of your questions individually were no big deal but all together is why it didn't get more answers sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd probably be better to do the formatting on the PHP end but your question appears to be wanting this done on the SQL end.  So, try this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(b.game_level_score) DESC) AS 'Rank'
    , a.username AS 'User Name'
    , MAX(b.game_level) AS 'Level Reached'
    , Convert(VarChar(8), DATEADD(millisecond,SUM(DATEDIFF(millisecond,0,CAST(b.time_spent AS DATETIME))),0), 108) AS 'Total Time Spent'
    , Cast(Cast(Round(AVG(Cast(b.stars AS Float)),1) AS Numeric(25,1)) AS VarChar(25)) AS 'Stars' 
    , Cast(SUM(b.game_level_score) AS Int) AS 'High Score'
    , a.current_state AS 'Online State'
FROM game_users a
    JOIN score b ON a.id = b.game_users_id
    GROUP BY a.username, a.current_state
```

I casted stars as a varchar (after rounding to one decimal) as that is the only way your going to get PHP to hold to a single decimal.  I left the other numeric value (high score) as an int.  PHP I should leave as an int and not display additional decimals points but if it does you'll have to cast as varchar as well.

Everything should work but since I don't have your tables I can't test past just valid syntax.  You'll need to do that... consider this code sample a guide to get you close.

The Row_Number() OVER Sort may need to go in the other direction depending on your preference.  Change to DESC or ASC as fits your needs.

Comment: Hi RThomas, Thanks for your help, it works just perfect :-) .. And I will keep in mind to only post 1 question at a time, though I normally prefer to keep one project in one thread to not spam the Forum! /Stig :-)

Comment: Since users get rewarded with points when you accept answers (or vote them up as good answers hint hint hint) asking multiple questions is actually preferable to forum users as well.  More points !!

Comment: Okay.. cool, thanks for the advice, I will Try that :-) .. I am as you see new to stackoverflow, and have not seen this system before, but, I must admit that the quality of this site is way higher than others I have seen! :-)